# Win10 + CodeBlocks + GDB ignores tabs

Tags: windows, debugging, io, gdb, codeblocks

I discovered today that on my machine, CodeBlocks + GDB ignores the tab characters in my input during debugging.  This seems arbitrary, not to mention it's going to make many K&R exercises difficult.

Is there a way I can fix this? Or at least a reason why it's happening to me and a Google search for this problem turns up nothing?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Commands-of-GUD.html):

"Because TAB serves as a completion command, you can’t use it to enter a tab as input to the program you are debugging with GDB. Instead, type C-q TAB to enter a tab."